# Alligation - when and why did it disappear?

Tags: mathematics

I have a book from 1795 where the mixing of quantities is done by Alligation.  Depending on the supplied data this can be Partial, Alternate, Medial or Total.

When I asked several teachers 'how would you calculate the mixture of quantities' 
they answered 'that's no longer on the syllabus' and would go no further.  Much later I found that Alligation is still taught at University to Pharmacy students.  The given methods do not necessarily give 'best' answers but do give quick and easy answers.

When and Why did Alligation leave the syllabus? 
JK

Comment: *When and Why did Alligation leave the syllabus?* This is surely something specific to where you live, because I can assure you that these types of problems are still extremely common and widely taught in both high school classes and (elementary) college classes. Try googling [mixture problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mixture+problems%22). They are also on pretty much every standardized test I can think of --- SAT, ACT, GRE, GMAT, NMAT (India), etc.

Comment: Pleasantly surprised; it just (slightly) lowered my opinion of the teachers I spoke to that they would not consider the problem.  Perhaps it was the way I phrased it (being based on the 1795 format).

Comment: Once **algebra** is commonly used, we can reduce or eliminate many of the old computational methods.  Not only alligation, but "the rule of three" and "the method of false position" and so on.

Comment: I think the 'quick and easy' rule of thumb has sometimes been overcome by the algebraic methods which with more effort give 'best answers'.  Thanks anyway.